# why is that str.count('') ≠ (from str.count('A') + str.count('B') + ... + str.count('Z'))

Tags: python, string, count, equals, false-positive

It (should, to me,) say `True` if there are only vowels in the string(phrase); otherwise says `False`. I don't understand why it always will return `False`, since (x >= x) always returns `True`.
I thank anyone for checking the solution to this query.

(str) -> bool

```
def valid_letter_sequence(abc):

    valid_letters = abc.count('A') + abc.count('E') + abc.count('I') + abc.count('O') + abc.count('U')
    counted_letters = abc.count('')
    if valid_letters >= counted_letters:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Observe:

```
>>> 'abc'.count('')
4
```

Passing an empty string to `count` gives you one more than the length of the string (because it finds the empty string at both ends as well as between every pair of characters).  Why don't you just use `len(abc)`?

More generally, there are better ways to do what you're doing.  Like maybe this:

```
def valid_letter_sequence(abc):
    return not (set(abc) - set('AEIOU'))
```

Comment: Certainly It's easier to use `len(abc)`and unfortunately didn't know that detail on `count`. Your comment sure was useful and will vote you up as soon as I get the reputation to do so.

I'm always trying to shorten my codes and your feedback is surely enlightening.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should of course be using `len()` to find the length of `abc`. Another disadvantage of `count()` is that it needs to scan the string again. Python already knows the length, so it's more efficient to just ask for it.

`all` allows the function to return as soon as it encounters a character not in "AEIOU". This is known as [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

```
def valid_letter_sequence(abc):
    return all(x in "AEIOU" for x in abc)
```